# How to use paginate with keyBy

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, pagination

I'm new to Laravel and having trouble paginating when using keyBy().

The following works:

```
$customers = Customers::paginate(10)
```

But the following gives an error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::keyBy()

```
$customers = Customers::keyBy('id')->paginate(10)
```

So how do I paginate when using keyBy?

I've tried inserting this into the boot method of AppServiceProvider.php with no effect:

```
if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
 Collection::macro('paginate', 
 function ($perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = []) {
 $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
 return (new LengthAwarePaginator(
 $this->forPage($page, $perPage), $this->count(), $perPage, $page,$options))->withPath('');
 });
}
```

Comment: `keyBy()` is a method of `Collection`, not `Builder`. Closures, like `->get()` or `->all()` transform a `Builder` to a `Collection`, so you'd have to call `Customers::get()->keyBy(...)`... But then you can't call `paginate()`, as that's a method of `Builder` and not `Collection`. You may need to rethink what you're trying to do, like maybe a `groupBy()` or `unique()` selection.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the insight. Will keep investigating.